# Mozilla pdf.js, How to I specify the filename for download?

Tags: php, pdf.js

I pass the location of the php file that contains the following code as parameter to the `viewer.html` file and it is displayed correctly but when clicking the download button in the pdf viewer the document name is always `document.pdf`. This poses a problem because of how many mobile users will be downloading files only to discover that all of their files have the the name `document.pdf` and that they (for most mobile browsers) can't change the filename before downloading.

Do I have to pass some arbitrary parameter to the file or redirect to self with the filename appended?

```
<?php
$content = "a binary representation of my pdf";
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="someFile.pdf"');
echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: Get rid of the quotes around the filename

Comment: No bacon. Same Results.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is take off "attachment; "

Comment: Also did not work. Thanks though for the quotes, didn't know that

Comment: I looked at some of my code and I guess it doesn't actually matter if the quotes are there or not, unless there's a space in the name, just like with HTML tag attributes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've run into this same issue. From the pdf.js's viewer.js source:

```
function getPDFFileNameFromURL(url) {
  var reURI = /^(?:([^:]+:)?\/\/[^\/]+)?([^?#]*)(\?[^#]*)?(#.*)?$/;
  //            SCHEME      HOST         1.PATH  2.QUERY   3.REF
  // Pattern to get last matching NAME.pdf
  var reFilename = /[^\/?#=]+\.pdf\b(?!.*\.pdf\b)/i;
  var splitURI = reURI.exec(url);
  var suggestedFilename = reFilename.exec(splitURI[1]) ||
                           reFilename.exec(splitURI[2]) ||
                           reFilename.exec(splitURI[3]);
  if (suggestedFilename) {
    suggestedFilename = suggestedFilename[0];
    if (suggestedFilename.indexOf('%') != -1) {
      // URL-encoded %2Fpath%2Fto%2Ffile.pdf should be file.pdf
      try {
        suggestedFilename =
          reFilename.exec(decodeURIComponent(suggestedFilename))[0];
      } catch(e) { // Possible (extremely rare) errors:
        // URIError "Malformed URI", e.g. for "%AA.pdf"
        // TypeError "null has no properties", e.g. for "%2F.pdf"
      }
    }
  }
  return suggestedFilename || 'document.pdf';
}
```

So the *majic* needs to come from the URL via the `reURI` regexp.

What you need to do is this:

```
http://domain.com/path/to/Named.pdf
http://domain.com/path/to/your/api?fileId=123&saveName=Named.pdf
```

Each of these will result in a save as filename of `Named.pdf` thanks to the regexp code above.

Comment: Its worth mentioning that PDFViewerApplication has setTitleUsingUrl(). You can use it to specify the file name for downloading . 

PDFViewerApplication.setTitleUsingUrl('http://www.mypdf.com/the-pdf.pdf');

Answer (score 5):

**Based on comments**

You can add this to wherever you're using the *viewer.js* file.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  // Wait for PDFViewerApplication object to exist
  PDFViewerApplication.setTitleUsingUrl('custom-file.pdf');
}, 10);
```

Then when you download the PDF it will have that filename